# JSONObject to arraylist? Why this JSONException?

Tags: android, json

I have this json

```
{
    "summary":
    {
        "total_count":2
    },
    "data":
    [
        {
            "id":"129393910815742",
            "name":"Mike Pollito"
        },
        {
            "id":"117161088707629",
            "name":"James Carballo"
        }
    ],
    "paging":
    {
        "cursors":
        {
            "after":"mUhn",
            "before":"QVFn"
        }
    }
}
```

and I need to save the ids in an `ArrayList` or any simple array.

Note:The number of ids may vary.

The problem is than i can easily get "total_count" with

```
int amigos = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONObject("summary").getInt("total_count");
```

but when i try to get any "id" when i call

```
JSONObject data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONObject("data");
```

i always get a JSONException

This is my buggy code

```
public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
                     JSONObject listatodoslosamigos = response.getJSONObject();
                    try {
                        int amigos = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONObject("summary").getInt("total_count");
                        JSONObject data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONObject("data");

                    } catch (JSONException e) {}
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Comment: "data" is an array. Try doing `JSONArray data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONObject("data");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` property in the JSON is an array, so you need to use `getJSONArray`, for instance;

```
JSONArray data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONArray("data");
```

You can iterator for a `JSONArray` using `.listIterator()` or via `.getJSONObject(index)`;

```
JSONArray data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject member = data.getJSONObject(0);
```

You can also use `JSONArray.toCollection` and `data.toArray` to turn a `JSONArray` into a normal Java collection or array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
JSONArray data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONArray("data");
```

Answer (score 0):

This line wrong
    JSONObject data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONObject("data");

```
Replace this line with below line
```

JSONObject data = listatodoslosamigos.getJSONArray("data");

```
B'caz data is json array type and you are trying to get json object so that use found this type of exception.
```